# Finding movement starting points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, time-series, mmqgis

I have multiple csv files (24+) with objects categorized by IDs, with their latitude and longitude, and timestamp. Each csv with a different timestamp specified in a column. 
There are multiple rows of latitudes and longitudes that often repeat themselves across time, but there are sudden changes in either latitude or longitude and I need to find the specific point where that movement started. I would want to capture even minimal Lat/longs changes, i.e. ID 101 has coordinates consisting of -20.0, 90, and an hour later it is at -20.0001, 90.002.
 I could also combine all the separate csv files into one. Basically, if I were to look at it in table form, I want to find the last row prior to any change in either the latitude or the longitude for each object.
I am not interested in finding the last row for each id if it is not preceded by a new lat/long.  
There can be multiple rows with the new lat/longs in the combined file, so `remove_duplicates()` in pandas via python is not an option. 
In other words, if we go the QGIS route for a solution, I would only want the output to have the points prior to a movement in time.

Is there a plugin that would make finding the point prior to coordinate change viable to perform this in QGIS?

Comment: Sort the data chronologically and then walk through the list, copying the data to a new list only if it has a different location than the preceding location. Be careful however, as there may be some signal wandering or floating point rounding errors. I suggest using a small tolerance to check the distance rather than a simple equality check.

Comment: If you get answers to say that there is no QGIS plug-in, then ask a new question that has a code attempt to ask about PyQGIS.

Comment: Replying to the first comment. Sounds very manual. Looking for a more automated approach for large amounts of data; hence my question about a possible plug-in